# Is it possible to emulate the notch from the Huawei P20 with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Huawei's P20 has an iPhone X like notch on the top of the screen. Can this "notch" be emulated in Android Studio so it is possible to test how an app is rendered on it without owning a P20?
I looked in the settings and it is possible to select a "skin" in the Hardware profile but Huawei's P20 is not part of it.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Follow the screen shots.

**first make sure 9.0 (api 28) run in your Emulater or testing device.**

1. Open System settings.

[image]

2. Open Developer option (*if u not found developer option please tap 7 times on build number. after that you get developer option.)

[image]

3. Scroll Down Until You Found -> Simulate a Display With a Cutout(click on it)

[image]

4. there is a multiple option to select screen Cutout style.

[image]

5. if you select **Tall Display Cutout** , your display is like that.

[image]

or if you select **Double Display Cutout** your display like.

[image]

Comment: It’s now `Display cutout`

Answer (score 15):

So I googled around and it's actually possible to emulate the notch in the developer preview of Android P.

To develope against that, you need to setup an emulator running Android P and then set the notch simulation in the developer settings of android.

Here is the official article to setup that notch simulation in [Android P Cutout API](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0#cutout)

Once that is done you can start testing and adapting to the new changes coming with these notches and Android P.

Answer (score 7):

I did this successfully on emulator "Pixel 3a API 30" by following these steps:

### How to Enable Developer mode

1. Go to `System → About emulated device → Build number`
2. Tap/click on "Build number" 5 or more times, until you see the message "you are now a developer"

### How to Enable notch/cutout on emulator

1. Go to System → Advanced → Developer options
2. Find and tap on option `Display cutout` (it is **not** `Simulate a Display With a Cutout` like on older versions)
3. Select the option which suits You best (notice the black hole on the top left corner, on the screenshot below)
   [image: Display cutout android emulator-developer options]

Comment: This worked great for me. I'm trying to create a "Pixel 5" emulator since one is not yet available. The Punch Hole cutout is almost perfect but it's a bit too big and a tiny bit off center after applying the Pixel 5 decorations from Device Art Generator onto the screenshot. Is it possible to customize the size or position of these cutouts?

Comment: I'm glad this helped :) Unfortunately, I don't know if custom notches are possible. If You find a solution, post it here, so I can add it to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, its possible to simulate notches in the Android Emulator:

1. Install Android P
2. Enable Developer Options

Follow the Steps( Make Sure You Have Enabled Developer Option Before Doing this):

- Simulate the notch(Inside Developers Options)
- Go to Settings
- Click on System
- Click on Advanced
- Select Developer Options
- Scroll Down Until You Found-> Simulate a Display With a Cutout(CLICK ON IT)

**This will trigger a Dialog showing Some Options:**

- None (This is the default behaviour)
- Corner Display Cutout(Display's a Cutout on Corner)
- Double Display Cutout (Shows Notches Up and Down)
- Tall Display Cutout (Shows a tall Notch at the Top)

**Select Double Display Cutout or Tall Display Cutout**

Comment: Can you add more details or screenshots? Because I cannot find the things you are talking about

Comment: @JanMoritz I have Updated the Steps in a detailed Way..Try Again and tell me if you need any help..